# Call a method from a Vue 3 watch that is in setup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar

I'm using Quasar and I'm moving from Vue 2 to Vue 3 and having a problem with watching a value that changes in a store file.

I have a layout page that has a select dropdown that changes the value of my background object in a store.

```
    store.methods.changeBackGround(geoBackgroundSelected.value)
```

I can read that on the inserted page with

```
{{ store.state.geoBackgroundSelected }}
```

and I do have

```
   import { ref , inject, computed, watch} from 'vue'
```

I have a watch added to my setup like :

```
    setup(){
    watch(() => store.state.geoBackgroundSelected, function() {  
    console.log('value changes detected');
    console.log(store.state.geoBackgroundSelected)
    checkStore('watch')     
    });
    },
```

But I can't call checkStore('watch')
I have a button that calls checkstore('button") and that works fine.  The console.log shows the the new value of store.state.geoBackgroundSelected but I get an error calling checkStore of.

```
  Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: checkStore is not defined
```

if I use this.checkStore I get:

```
   Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checkStore')
```

I've tried using

```
       watch:{
       geoBackground:{
       handler(){
       console.log('watch')
       console.log(geoBackground)
      },
     deep: true
     },
```

But that does not get called.
I've tried replacing geoBackground with store.state.geoBackgroundSelected but that does not like the .'s.

Is my problem with my store? my watchers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `checkStore` method implemented as options API? I think you should either implement it in `setup`, or setup a watcher with Options API format.

I did setup [small demo on playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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). It implements a method that is accessible by both watcher and button while using Composition API.

[Same sample, but in options API](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when using the `watch` function, you need to have the context of the callback function be the Vue instance. Therefore, if you have a method like `checkStore` that you want to access within the watch callback, you should use an **arrow function** to correctly capture the component's context. This ensures that `this` refers to the Vue instance.

```
watch(() => store.state.geoBackgroundSelected, () => {  
  console.log('value changes detected');
  console.log(store.state.geoBackgroundSelected);
  this.checkStore('watch'); // Using arrow function to correctly capture the component's context
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I get the same two errors trying to find checkStore.  I think it's because it's under SetUp

Comment: @Bill Sorry to hear it didn't work. I've only used the Composition API for Vue3, and it seems like you're using the Options API.
There is some info here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example
Perhaps trying to use the same concept of a named function instead of the keyword `function` makes any difference? Otherwise I'm out of ideas, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks-- I'll give it a shot and keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify Arturs Buls answer a bit but I got it to work.  Here's what I did. First added the watcher in the options API

```
   geoBackground (newVal) {
   this.geoBackgroundChange(newVal)
   // this.checkStore(newVal)
    }
   },
```

then added geoBackground in my return but added a computed value

```
    geoBackground: computed(() => store.state.geoBackgroundSelected),
```

That did trigger the watch and I was able to call the this.checkStore.  Really I had to call my background changer which is showing in the code above.

In my opinion there was way too much code to change and to put into setup.  following is a sample for only one condition

```
     case "ArcGIS":
        if (typeof this.lbackground !== 'undefined' && this.lbackground) {
            this.map.removeLayer(this.lbackground);
        };
        //ArvGIS
        let mapLink =
            '<a href="http://www.esri.com/">Esri</a>';
        let wholink =
            'i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community';
        this.lbackground = L.tileLayer(
            'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
                attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ', ' + wholink,
                maxZoom: 18
            }).addTo(this.map);
        break
```

Thanks for the help